# How do I get to add my own content to My umbraco Page?

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

I'm playing around with umbraco for the first time. I've created my own test page and it displays perfectly fine.

When I go into Visual studio to edit the page as I would expect to (in this case just a little test). If Files to display in my page (I've check the source too can't see it?

I've tried a whole host of standard tag's such as p and h1 to get it to show. But so far its still not showing.

What am I missing?

```
    @inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<ContentModels.WintyTest>
    @using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedModels;
     @{
        Layout = "contentPage.cshtml";
        }

        <text>this is a test is my hard coded string 3</text>
         @Model.Value("bodyText")
```

Comment: Basics I guess :-)

Comment: Have you published the changes, not just saved them?

Comment: To me the middle paragraph doesn't have any sense.